# Pandas - Filtering alternate Monday

Tags: pandas, date

I have a Dataframe that has sales data by day. I would like to be able to filter out sales data of every alternate Monday. For example, if I select June 27 the next date I would like to filter would be July 11 and the next date would be July 25 and so on.

I have my Dataframe as below

```
sale_date, count
2022-06-27, 100
2022-07-01, 150
2022-07-07, 100
2022-07-11, 150
2022-06-20, 100
2022-07-25, 150
```

I would expect the output to be

```
sale_date, count
2022-06-27, 100
2022-07-11, 150
2022-07-25, 150
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# convert to datetime
date = pd.to_datetime(df['sale_date'])

# is the day a Monday (0 = Monday)?
m1 = date.dt.weekday.eq(0)
# is the week an "even" week?
m2 = date.dt.isocalendar().week.mod(2).eq(0)

# if both conditions are True, keep the row
out = df[m1&m2]
```

output:

```
    sale_date  count
0  2022-06-27    100
3  2022-07-11    150
5  2022-07-25    150
```

intermediates:

```
    sale_date  count  weekday  weekday.eq(0)  week  week.mod(2)  week.mod(2).eq(0)
0  2022-06-27    100        0           True    26            0               True
1  2022-07-01    150        4          False    26            0               True
2  2022-07-07    100        3          False    27            1              False
3  2022-07-11    150        0           True    28            0               True
4  2022-06-20    100        0           True    25            1              False
5  2022-07-25    150        0           True    30            0               True
```

Comment: I like this answer, but would this be subject to a week 53 to a week 1 scenario at the start of a new year?

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn it depends how OP wants to handle the week numbers, this doesn't change the general logic. Alternative ways are possible if needed ;)

Comment: Ok, I wasn't trying to pick, I just study your stuff A LOT so I wanted to make sure I understood at least enough to see that this particular answer might have a hole (even if rare)

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn no worries, I'd be happy to update if needed ;)

Comment: No its ok =) thanks for the response I'm off to study more of your stuff haha

Answer (score 0):

```
df11=df1.resample("2w-mon",closed="left",on="sale_date")["count"].first().reset_index()
df11.assign(sale_date=df11.sale_date-pd.Timedelta(days=7))
```

out：

```
  sale_date  count
0 2022-06-27    100
1 2022-07-11    100
2 2022-07-25    150
```